# In Go can I return a struct that meets an interface without access to that interface?

Tags: go, interface

I think the best way to explain this is by example, so here it is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// Greeter greets with a Greeting.
type Greeter interface {
    Greet() Greeting
}

// A Greeting has a string representation.
type Greeting interface {
    String() string
}

type Hello struct {}

// Hello greets by returning itself...
func (h *Hello) Greet() *Hello {
    return h
}

// ...because Hello also has a string representation.
func (h *Hello) String() string {
    return "Hello"
}

// But Go says Hello doesn't implement Greeter.
func main() {
    var g interface{} = &Hello{}
    g, ok := g.(Greeter)
    fmt.Println(ok)
}
```

This prints `false`. You can run and play with it: https://play.golang.org/p/A_2k_ku_Q2

In my real case the struct `Hello` and the interfaces for `Greeter` and `Greeting` are in **different packages** that do not import each other and I wanted to keep it that way. I'm perhaps missing some understanding of interfaces in Go but after reading so much about it I still can't put my finger on it. Would you guys have any pointers for me? Maybe another approach for the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the return type of `Greet` have to be exactly `Greeting` for the type to fit the `Greeter` interface?

Comment: @user2357112 As far as I know yes it has. But as I mentioned above, in my case the interface and the struct are in separate packages. So where I define the method `Greet() *Hello` I don't have access to the interface.

Comment: The method definitions have to match perfectly for the interface to be satisfied. Even if you did `type Mystring string` then tried to return a `Mystring` from the `String()` method, it wouldn't satisfy the interface for `Greeting`.

Comment: Just adding my voice to the chorus. In order to satisfy the `Greeter` interface, the return type of `Greet` must be `Greeting`.

Comment: Okay, cool. Now that we've stipulated that about interfaces I ask: what changes, if any, could be done so I can make a method in another package return a value that is accepted by a function defined here, without importing each other?

Comment: Only one should have to import the other one. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: @AndySchweig My reasoning is this: the second package is just an adapter and it should have no knowledge of any of the things it connects, as long as its types adhere to the their interfaces. Perhaps this approach is ill conceived? Oh and also because when I did and then I imported this adapter into the `_test` file Go whined about interfaces mismatch again saying that type `T` is not the same as `package.T` only they're the same, but one is referenced outside the package, hence the package qualifier.

Comment: Can the connector package define the necessary interfaces so that the other packages that use it just have to import the connector package?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As stated in the comments, problem here is once your interface has this signature:

```
type Greeter interface {
    Greet() Greeting
}
```

The any valid implementation must use exactly `Greeting` as the return type.

But, as the documentation shows, you don't need to give the interface a name:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types

In order to be able to implement what you need, you might declare the interface directly in the return value, without giving it a name.

```
// Greeter greets with anything that has a String() method
type Greeter interface {
    Greet() interface{ String() string }
}
```

Then your `Greet()` function for `Hello` can do this:

```
// Hello greets by returning itself...
func (h *Hello) Greet() interface{ String() string } {
   return h
}
```

Find here a modified playground showing the working example:

https://play.golang.org/p/HteA_9jFd4