# golang struct not implementing interface?

Tags: go, struct, interface

I am a beginner with go so bear with me on this. I have an interface defined as the following:

```
type DynamoTable interface {
    Put(item interface{}) interface{ Run() error }
}
```

also I have a `Repo` struct like so:

```
type TenantConfigRepo struct {
    table DynamoTable
}
```

and i have a struct `dynamo.Table` which has a `Put` function defined like so:

```
func (table dynamo.Table) Put(item interface{}) *Put
```

and the `Put` struct has a `Run` function as follows:

```
func (p *Put) Run() error
```

What I am trying to do is have a generic `DynamoTable` interface which will then be used for mocking and unit tests. however this is causing an issue with creating a new Repo:

```
func newDynamoDBConfigRepo() *TenantConfigRepo {
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
    db := dynamo.New(sess)
    table := db.Table(tableName) //=> this returns a type dynamo.Table
    return &TenantConfigRepo{
        table: table,
    }
}
```

This however is throwing an error like so

`cannot use table (variable of type dynamo.Table) as DynamoTable value in struct literal: wrong type for method Put (have func(item interface{}) *github.com/guregu/dynamo.Put, want func(item interface{}) interface{Run() error})`

this is very strange for me because from what i see is the interface that has a `Run() error` should be sufficient for the `Put` struct since it has the same signature. I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> wrong type for method Put (have func(item interface{}) *github.com/guregu/dynamo.Put, want func(item interface{}) interface{Run() error})

your function returns a `*Put`.   The interface expects an `interface{Run() error}`.  A `*Put` might satisfy this interface, but they're still different types.  *A function signature returning a type that satisfies that interface is **not** interchangeable with a function signature returning that interface.*

So, start by giving your interface a name.  We refer to it in 2 places, and you should avoid anonymous interface (and struct) definitions because they have no inherent benefit and make your code more verbose and less DRY.

```
type Runner interface{
   Run() error
}
```

Now update DynamoTable to use that interface

```
type DynamoTable interface {
    Put(item interface{}) Runner
}
```

You say `dynamo.Table` is outside of your control.  But you can create a new type equal to `dynamo.Table` and then override the `put` method.

In overridden method, we'l cast our `dynamoTable` back to `dynamo.Table`, call the original `dynamo.Table.Put`, and then return the result.

```
type dynamoTable dynamo.Table

func (table *dynamoTable) Put(item interface{}) Runner {
  return (*dynamo.Table)(table).Put(item)
}
```

`dynamo.Table` Can still return a `*Put` because `*Put` implements `Runner`.  The return value will be `Runner` and the underlying type will be `*Put`.  Then the interface will be satisfied, and that error will be fixed.

https://go.dev/play/p/y9DKgwWbXOO illustrates how this retype and override process works.

Comment: I sadly do not have access to the dynamo.Table as it is an external library so modifying that can't be done. as for the anonymous interface i was reading through stackoverflow before posting the question and i came across this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526476/in-go-can-i-return-a-struct-that-meets-an-interface-without-access-to-that-inter which i thought to be the same problem.

Comment: makes sense.  Take a look at my edits

Comment: Added a go playground link that proves out how this `Put` method override would work and also made a small fix to my code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! i think if i am not mistaken this is can be linked to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190170/go-interface-method-returning-interface-doesnt-match-method-returning-concrete ? am i correct in assuming this?

Comment: Yep, same solution, agreed.